# How to show the soft numeric keypad without an input field?

Tags: android

I have an OpenGL application that needs to show the soft keyboard for devices without physical ones for user input such as username or numbers in a few cases.  In the case of numeric input, is there any way to show the numeric keypad instead of the alphabetic keyboard?  I'm not using any text edit fields or anything, just the `InputMethodManager`:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(glView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

The only method I've found that looks remotely helpful is `InputMethodManager.setInputMethod` but that takes an `IBinder` token and a `String` id, neither of which is explained very well in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#setInputMethod%28android.os.IBinder,%20java.lang.String%29).  I get the impression that it's not the right way to go, though.

If I were using an edit field, it would be simple and obvious, and I've found dozens of answers for that, but that's not what I'm doing, because it's an OpenGL game, so I have to just displaying the keyboard manually as above.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for since it is more of a hack than a real solution, but a few things come to mind that might work (that is if you can't get a real solution).

An `EditText` with `View.INVISIBLE` set.  Although, you might not be able to set focus here.

Put an EditText behind your `GLSurfaceView` and focus it.  So it’s technically visible (from a code standpoint) but invisible to the user.